# How photo tag is made in facebook ?

Tags: java, php, facebook

How photo tag is made in Facebook i want to know which programming languages tag is made with 
and if any one have example he can share it with me

Comment: Are you referring to **HTML** `<img>` tags?

Comment: no Facebook photo tag  to tag friend in photo in Facebook

Comment: It was probably php in some way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely done with javascript. Here is one of possible solutions (jQuery): http://karlmendes.com/2010/07/jquery-photo-tag-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to the use the graph API. For example, I could show Mark Zuckerberg's profile image with the following markup:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=150" alt="mark's fb profile photo" />
```

Note that 4 is Mark Zuckerberg's user id. You could also use his username "zuck".

For documentation on the graph api, go to the [facebook developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)

Edit:
Apparently the user was asking about the tagging feature. Facebook's platform is php, the ui of the feature is in javascript.

Comment: i dont mean this you know when i tag a friend in a photo ? ?  how facebook made this what is the coding lang ?

Comment: javascript in the browser, php on the server

Comment: Tim, you didn't get the question.

Comment: Is no one reading the Edit comment at the bottom?